# XComment added before closing tag

Tags: c#, xml

Visual Studio 2008.  I am using System.Xml.Linq.

I'm writing an XDocument XML file and I want to add a comment line before or after an XML element.

For some reason, the XML serializer inserts the comment in the middle of the XML element.

```
// Create an XComment
//
string roleComment = string.Format("{0} Role ID={1}", myRole.roleType, myRole.roleId);
XComment xRoleComment = new XComment(roleComment);

// Create an XElement
//
XElement xRoleId = new XElement("Role_id", myRole.GUID);

// Add the XComment to the XElement
xRoleId.Add(xRoleComment);
```

My output ends up unexpectedly with the comment before the closing tag:

```
<Role_id>2510<!--ROLE_TYPE_MASTER Role ID=130--></Role_id>
```

How do I add the comment so that it ends up outside the element tags?  Before or after is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can add that comment node to *parent* of `Role_id` element.First get the parent then add the `XComment`.Or create a parent element for `Role_id`:

```
 XElement parent = new XElement("parent", 
            new XElement("Role_id", myRole.GUID), 
            new XComment(roleComment));
```

Or use [`XElement.AddAfterSelf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.addafterself%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
xRoleId.AddAfterSelf(xRoleComment);
```

Comment: Added to the parent, thanks. Still, I thought it was strange that the comment ended up inside the tags.

Comment: @JohnJesus because you are adding it to the element directly.that's what the `Add` method does.. :)

Comment: Ah right. Yeah, if I was adding a child element, it would be between the tags, also. Got it.